# Comprobar cuantas veces se repite un carácter en un array y mostrar en un map

Tags: javascript, array

Debo guardar en un map los items del array con el número de veces que se repiten, he encontrado este código que funciona pero que no consigo entender del todo, alguien me lo puede explicar? También si hay otra manera de hacerlo. Gracias!!

```
var letters = ["D", "A", "V", "I", "D"];

var numLetters = letters.reduce(function(countLetter, letter){
  countLetter[letter] = (countLetter[letter] || 0) + 1;
  return countLetter;
}, {})

console.log(numLetters);

Output: {D: 2, A: 1, V: 1, I: 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> El método reduce() aplica una función a un acumulador y a cada valor
>   de una array (de izquierda a derecha) para reducirlo a un único valor.

**¿Qué significa esto?** Que la función lo que hará será operar cada valor del `array` y guardar el resultado de la operación en el acumulador.

**¿Qué es el acumulador y como lo uso?** Esto nos lleva directamente a los argumentos que podemos usar en la función que ejecuta `reduce()`. En nuestro caso:

```
function(countLetter, letter) { ... }
```

El primer argumento corresponde a nuestro acumulador (en nuestro caso se llama *countLetter* y el segundo corresponde a cada uno de los elementos de nuestro `array` (en nuestro caso se llama *letter*.

**¿Y qué es lo hace esa función en sus tripas?**

```
countLetter[letter] = (countLetter[letter] || 0) + 1;
return countLetter;
```

Lo que hace es tratar de crear una propiedad en nuestro acumulador, usando como nombre la letra que esté iterando en ese momento. En caso de que esa propiedad no exista la creará y le dará valor **0** para después sumarle 1 y en caso de que ya exista le dará el valor de lo que ya tenga + 1.

Por último, cuando se haya recorrido el `array` por completo, la función retornará el acumulador.

Se podría hacer de otra manera, claro está, pero sería básicamente imitar lo que hace la función `reduce()` pero en un mayor número de lineas.

```js
const letters = ["D", "A", "V", "I", "D"];
const letras_contadas = contar_letras(letters);

console.log(letras_contadas);

function contar_letras (letras) {
  let letras_contadas = {};

  letras.forEach(function (letra) {
    if (letra in letras_contadas) {
      letras_contadas[letra]++;
    }
    else {
      letras_contadas[letra] = 1;
    }
  });

  return letras_contadas;
}
```

**Referencia:** [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, me cuesta entender esta parte de la función; countLetter[letter] = (countLetter[letter] || 0) + 1;
return countLetter; entiendo || como un operador OR, que significa en este caso? Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Se puede dar un valor condicional a una variable. Con `countLetter[letter] = (countLetter[letter] || 0) ` lo que estamos haciendo es que `countLetter[letter]` va a valer lo que tenga `countLetter[letter]` a no ser que este devuelve un valor considerado **falsy** (null, undefined, 0, false, empty, NaN...) en cuyo caso va a valer 0.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!